# What are the best examples of natural keys in SQL?

Tags: sql, database-design

I've been reading the great debates about natural vs surrogate keys in data modeling, and to be clear I'm not trying to get into that thorny question here. All I want to know is what are some of the best examples of good natural keys?

All I seem to find online are keys that someone thought *might* be good but turn out not to be, like social security numbers. (For that one: privacy concerns, not everyone has one, reused after death, can be changed after identity theft, can double as business tax id.)

My own guess is that internationally standardized codes (ISBN, VIN, country codes, language codes) would make good keys.

Comment: Note that your examples, such as ISBN, are in some other context invented for the purpose of identification.  There keys are natural from the point of view of the database builder, but they are just as artificial as surrogate keys.  It's just that the DBMS doesn't have to do the inventing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Invoice numbers, vehicle registration numbers, scheduled flight codes, login names, email addresses, employee numbers, room numbers, UPC codes. There are also many thousands of industry, public and international standards for everything from currencies, languages, financial instruments, chemical compounds and medical diagnoses. All of these are potentially good candidates for key attributes. Some sensible criteria for choosing and designing keys are: Simplicity, Stability and Familiarity (i.e. familiar within the business or other context in which they are used).

Some people seem to struggle with the choice of "natural" key attributes because they hypothesize situations where a particular key might not be unique in some given population. This misses the point. The point of a key is to impose a business rule that attributes must and will be unique for the population of data within a particular table at any given point in time. The table always represents data in a particular and hopefully well-understood context (the "business domain" AKA "domain of discourse"). It is the intention/requirement to apply a uniqueness constraint within that domain that matters.

For example, if my website requires each user to supply a unique email address when they register then email address may be a valid choice of key in the database supporting that website. The fact that there are other populations of people in other domains where email addresses are not required to be unique does not necessarily invalidate that choice of key for my website.

Answer (score 3):

Assume, there is a table named **person**. When we use the columns **LastName, FirstName** and **Address** together as a key, then this will be a natural key as those columns are completely natural to people, and there is also a logical relationship between the columns in the table.

Comment: What if you want to keep track of where a person has lived over time? They don't become a new person by moving.

Comment: Lets say you have two women living in an apartment: Jill Brown and Jill Bravo.  Ms. Bravo marries a Joe Brown.  She's now Jill Brown, just like her roommate.  Jill Brown needs to have her name updated in the database, but can't because it's a violation of primary key.  The natural key won't work...

Comment: It's a good job that no parent has ever named a child after themselves either.

Comment: Sometimes name does make sense as a key attribute. I worked on one database where a table keyed on personal names was used for guesses about gender and ethnicity based on names. A sports tournament is perhaps another good example. If two competitors on the same sports team had the same name then I expect they might agree to style their names slightly differently to ensure that name could be used to identify them. So the example of using names in a key seems reasonable in some circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

Your DNA code would be one really good example of a natural key in real life.

Comment: Not if you have an identical twin.

Comment: Even identical twins don't have the same DNA

Comment: I don't think DNA is a great example of a natural key. I guess it is stable but it's hardly familiar or simple.